# How can I pass an array to an ejs template in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to pass an array which contains objects to views of ejs in express, but it doesn't work.

In server,

```
var roominfo = function(roomname){
this.roomname=roomname;
};

room_info_array= new Array(1);
room_info_array[0]=new roominfo("room");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
res.render('login',{room_info:room_info_array});
});
```

In client,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <%= JSON.stringify(room_info) %>
</script>
```

this shows error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & ".

```
var data = [{&quot;roomname&quot;:&quot;room&quot;}]"
```

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <% JSON.stringify(room_info) %>
</script>
```

However this shows data is undefined.

How should I pass the array to ejs correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In EJS echoing something is done with

```
<%= %>
```

or

```
<%- %>
```

In the last example you're not echoing anything, so nothing is passed to `data` and it's undefined.

In the first example you're also escaping the echoed content, so try using echoing the string unescaped as that will remove the entities.

```
var data = <%- JSON.stringify(room_info) %>
```