# ReferenceError when trying to use a variable in an EJS template file

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm having a heap of trouble just trying to get an EJS template file to recognise a variable that stores the rows of an SQLite3 table query in a corresponding .js file. I get a ReferenceError for the variable I used in the EJS file when launching the server and trying to access that route.

For context it's a micro blog project where I'd like authors to have the ability to save draft articles in to a database and for the user to be able to come back and modify or publish them later.

Here's my 'author.js' file:

```
// Author Page
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const assert = require('assert');

/**
 * @desc retrieves draft articles
 */
router.get("/author-home", (req, res, next) => {

    //Use this pattern to retrieve data
    //NB. it's better NOT to use arrow functions for callbacks with this library
    global.db.all("SELECT * FROM draftArticles", function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        next(err); //send the error on to the error handler
      } else {
        res.json(rows);
      }
    });
});


/**
 * @desc Renders the author page
 */
router.get("/author", (req, res) => {
    res.render("author-home", data);
  });


module.exports = router;
```

In my 'author-home.ejs' file, I'm trying to insert various article properties in a  element like so:

```
<td><% data[0].article_title %> </td>
<td><% data[0].article_subtitle %> </td>
```

...etc.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can also post the code for my 'index.js' file if that's helpful. Many thanks in advance

EDIT:

After some suggestions were sent and the scope issue of the  'data' variable was highlighted, I corrected my code in `author.js` (at least, I believe so) to the following:

```
    // Author Page
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const assert = require('assert');





router.get('/author-home', (req, res, next) => {
    global.db.all('SELECT * FROM draftArticles', function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("No data found.")
        next(err); //send the error on to the error handler
        return;
      }
  
      res.render('author-home', { data: rows });
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

However, I still receive a `referenceError` when trying to access `data` in my EJS file.

I also tried, as was suggested, to pass static data like so:

```
let dummyData = "This is test data";

router.get('/author-home', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('author-home', { data: dummyData });
});
```

Also receiving a `referenceError`.

Comment: have you tried with set static data in your data variable and pass to the template? may be an issue with the data.

Comment: The `data` variable in `res.render("author-home", data);` is undefined. Or at least i do not see where you define it and assign any value to it.

Comment: Thanks @Molda, I've corrected this. Unfortunately I still get a referenceError when trying to access `data` in my author-home.ejs file

Comment: @KaushikMakwana thanks for the advice, I updated my post showing what I tried in terms of passing static data. Unfortunately, it didn't result in any success

Comment: @DanWhite in your template you expect the data to be an array of objects, something like `{ data: [ { article_title: 'abc', ... } ]}` and you tried `{ data: dummyData }` where dummyData is a string not an array. Does it not seem obvoius to you?

Comment: @Molda it was so obvious that I thought it would be implied by the fact I said I tried to pass static data, that I tried to access only `data` as opposed to `data[index]` in my ejs file when I tried this method. Also, the problem you're referring to would result in a `typeError`, not a `referenceError`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not defined "data". You need to define it if you want to send an array you can use
[How can I pass an array to an ejs template in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592760/how-can-i-pass-an-array-to-an-ejs-template-in-express)

your code should be like..

```js
// Author Page
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const assert = require('assert');





router.get('/author-home', (req, res, next) => {
  global.db.all('SELECT * FROM draftArticles', function(err, rows) {
    if (err || !rows || !rows.length) {
      console.log("No data found.")
      // also try to log rows here to see what you are getting. does the "rows" have atricle_title etc attributes or not?
      next(err || new Error("No Data found!")); //send the error on to the error handler
      return;
    }
    res.render('author-home', {
      data: rows
    });
  });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response - I followed all of the changes in the thread that you sent me but unfortunately, I still get a `ReferenceError`.